# Calling operator new in a CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, cuda

In the following, I'm trying to allocate device memory in kernel `create_A()` for a trivial object `A`, then delete it from another kernel `delete_A()`. It seems the allocation of `ptr_` in `create_A` does not persist in device memory after `create_A` returns.

## main1.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

class A {
public:
    int a;

    __device__ A(int x)
        : a(x) { 
        printf("\nA()"); 
    }
    
    __device__ ~A() { printf("\n~A()"); }
};

__global__ void create_A(A* ptr_) {

    printf("\nCreating A...");

    ptr_ = new A(7);

    return;
}

__global__ void delete_A(A* ptr_) {

    printf("\nA.a = %d \nDeleting A...", ptr_->a);

    delete ptr_;
     
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    A* ptr_ = NULL;
    
    create_A<<<1,1>>>(ptr_);

    delete_A<<<1,1>>>(ptr_);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != CUDA_SUCCESS)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\".\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Creating A...
A()
kernel launch failed with error "an illegal memory access was encountered".
```

On the other hand, if I make `ptr_` a global variable as in the following, it works.

## main2.cu

```
class A {
public:
    int a;

    __device__ A(int x) 
        : a(x) { 
        
        printf("\nA()"); 
    }
    
    __device__ ~A() { printf("\n~A()"); }
};

__device__ A* ptr_;

__global__ void create_A() {

    printf("\nCreating A...");

    ptr_ = new A(7);

    return;
}

__global__ void delete_A() {
        
    printf("A.a is: %d", ptr_->a);

    printf("\nDeleting A...");

    delete ptr_;
     
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    
    create_A<<<1,1>>>();

    delete_A<<<1,1>>>();

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaError_t cudaerr = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaerr != CUDA_SUCCESS)
        printf("kernel launch failed with error \"%s\".\n",
               cudaGetErrorString(cudaerr));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Creating A...
A()
A.a is: 7
Deleting A...
~A()
```

Why does the allocation of `ptr_` persist on the device only in the second case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems the allocation of ptr_ in create_A does not persist in device memory after create_A returns.

It *does* persist, but you are losing the pointer to it. You seem to be unfamiliar with C++ scope rules. Consider the following (non-CUDA) C++ example:

```
void allocate(A* ptr) {
    // modifies a local copy of ptr, not the one in caller's scope
    ptr = new A(7);
} // pointer is lost here, memory leak

A* ptr = nullptr;
allocate(ptr);
ptr->something(); // error: ptr is still null in this scope
```

So in short, you're passing `null` to `delete_A`:

```
printf("A.a is: %d", ptr_->a); // ptr_ is null, access violation
```

In regular C++, you would simply pass the pointer by reference (or return it by value) to fix the problem:

```
void allocate(A*& ptr) {
    // modifies ptr in caller's scope
    ptr = new A(7);
}

A* ptr = nullptr;
allocate(ptr);
ptr->something(); // works fine!
```

If you're using CUDA < 6.5, you cannot do that, as kernel arguments may not be references. You need to either store the pointer as a global (as you did), or allocate memory for it and copy it from and to the device.

If  you're using CUDA 6.5 or above, you may use Unified Memory to allocate `ptr` through `cudaMallocManaged` and pass it as reference as demonstrated above.

Comment: Thanks. Why can I not then use void allocate(A** ptr)? Is it because this passes the pointer's host address, and this cannot be modified from the device?

Comment: You can use that signature, but you won't be able to call it with `create_A<<<1, 1>>>(&ptr)`  for the reason you mentioned. You must use `cudaMalloc` (or a variant) to allocate GPU-accessible storage for your pointer.

Comment: "kernel arguments may not be references" - they in fact may as of at least CUDA 6.5.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to change the value of a pointer(not the obj pointed), you need a two-level point.

```cpp
__global__ void create_A(A** ptr_) {

    printf("\nCreating A...");

    *ptr_ = new A(7);

    return;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).